# embedding excel into form lotus domino

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I need to embed an excel sheet into a form so multiple users can fill in their part of the sheet. 
When I save the document, without editing the excel file I embedded, I can open the document in a view. 
If I want to edit the document I just saved, I get the following msg:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJAhP.png
Another issue is, when I fill in some parts of the excel table and save the excel and then save the form, on the view pane I see the document but when I want to access it I get the following msg :
"Document has been deleted." 
Is there some work-around to make the document not read-only so the excel file could be modified? or some other method to insert the excel file into a form?
The functionality that I am trying to achieve is multiple users filling in same excel through lotus notes client.
I am working with lotus notes/domino 8.5 and the database is local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an OLE object to a form in Lotus Notes, you need to tell the Notes whether you want a new copy of the object to be created for each document. If you don't, then Notes simply launches the object that is on the form -- the same object for every user and every document that uses the form, and it is read-only.

To do this, you need to add a Rich Text field somewhere on the form, go to the Form Properties dialog, click on the Launch tab (looks vaguely like a rocket), select Auto-Launch "-First OLE Object-", and Create Object in Field "-First Rich Text Field-".  This way, every time you create a document with the form, a new copy of the object will be created will be saved with the document, which also allows it to be editable when you re-open the document.

Comment: Purfect. Another thing I would add is to hide the OLE object, since that same object will be copied into the rich text field, assuming that you dont want to have 2 worksheets showing while only one of them serves the purpose :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option for you to consider may be to store the actual Excel file on a shared network drive and only store a reference to it in Lotus Notes (IE path and filename).  You could have a button in Notes that opens the Excel file (script) given this path/filename.  The script needs to check that the Excel file can be opened for read/write access (IE no lock on it as in use by someone else) and if not then report to the user that it's currently being edited.

I guess there will be a final 'complete' status for the Excel document - maybe at this point you grab the Excel file and embed in the Notes Document - and then set a status flag in the Notes document as complete (or whatever) for view purposes.

Just a thought & good luck.

Comment: thx, but that solution would not work as I need to have the form reused as a template many times, IE when new document is created the excel file needs to be in its original form without any input. Also, the excel file will be filled in at different stages and by different users.

Comment: You may have missed my point?  We have a network share that all users can see.  Then we create a notes doc and hit a button to create an Excel (blank) file via script.  The script gives the file a unique name and saves this info in the Notes doc.  Other Notes users can see this newly created notes document and when they open the notes doc, they can see summary info but can also click on the open Excel button - when they click on open we simply create an instance of Excel and pass the filename and path stored in Notes - so hey presto, they open the Excel doc that was created by another user.

Comment: So we're just using Notes to 'drive' the process.

Comment: One point in favor of Phil's approach is that OLE objects have, at times, been a bit unreliable. I.e., I've seen issues when users have different versions of a Microsoft product, and the objects created by one version just won't load any more. Now, I admit it's been a very long time since I saw this, but it always spooked me, and here's why: if you have an Excel file that won't open, at least you have the file and you can email it to someone who can possibly fix it for you; but if you have an OLE object embedded in a Notes database, you're probably stuck.

Comment: So if you stick with OLE, my recommendation would be to also have a process somewhere, automated or not, that saves the objects as regular old files at some point in their lifecycle.